# Sending and receiving data to multiple clients using PHP Sockets

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

I am using [SocketServer.class.php](https://gist.github.com/navarr/459321) for recieving data from and sending to the remote client from my server. It works with just one client perfectly. 
The client being a digital meter which sends data over TCP/IP using a GPRS Modem connected to it. Each meter is distinguished using it's meter ID, which ranges from 1 to 247 and the data is passed and recived in ASCII. 
The PHP Code is run in a windows command shell and saves the input readings to the database.
Now when trying to do the same with two meters with ID 1 and 2, it doesn't work. I have no idea how to proceed. I am attaching the code I have performed till now.

```
    <?php

require_once("SocketServer.class.php"); // Include the File
    $server = new SocketServer("192.168.1.5",5001); // Create a Server binding to the given ip address and listen to port 5001for connections
    $server->max_clients = 247; // Allow no more than 247 people to connect at a time

    $server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Run handle_connect every time someone connects
    $server->hook("INPUT","handle_input");// Run handle_input whenever text is sent to the server

/*  //main loop
for($i=1; $i<=247; $i++) {  




    }*/
$server->infinite_loop(); // Run Server Code Until Process is terminated.*/

/*$server   ->  loop_once();*/


function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input)
{
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String","");
}

function handle_input($server,&$client,$input)
{


        // You probably want to sanitize your inputs here
        $trim = trim($input); // Trim the input, Remove Line Endings and Extra Whitespace.

        saveInput($input); // this function would save the values to database as it is received
        $output =   "65030063002F"; //65 -> Meter ID 101 in HEX 03 -> function 0063 -> start register 002F -> Number of registers
        $hexad  =   hexToStr($output);
        $hexad  .=  crc16($hexad);
        echo $hexad;
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,&$hexad,"");

}
function saveInput($input)
{
        $res = strToHex($input);
        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($res)-1; $i+=2)
        {
            $string[] = $res[$i].$res[$i+1];
        }
        if(hexdec($string[0]) > 0 && hexdec($string[0]) < 248) {
        echo "Meter --> ".hexdec($string[0])."<br>";
        echo "Function --> ".hexdec($string[1])."<br>";
        $byte = hexdec($string[2]);
        echo "Byte Count --> ".$byte."<br>";
/*      $l=40100; 
            for($k=3; $k<($byte+3); $k+=2) {

        echo "Register $l --> ".hexdec($string[$k].$string[$k+1])."<br>";
        $l++;
        }*/
        echo "<br>";
        }
}
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex .= str_pad(dechex(ord($string[$i])),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

    }
    $hex = trim($hex);
    return $hex;
}
 function crc16($data)
 {
   $crc = 0xFFFF;
   for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++)
   {
     $crc ^=ord($data[$i]);

        for ($j = 8; $j !=0; $j--)
        {
            if (($crc & 0x0001) !=0)
            {
                $crc >>= 1;
                $crc ^= 0xA001;
            }
            else
                $crc >>= 1;
        }
    }   
    $crc = dechex($crc);
    $order = str_split($crc, 2);
    $order = array_reverse($order);
    $crc    =   implode($order);
    $crc    =   hexToStr($crc);
   return $crc;
 }
?>
```

The return values are all stored in Hexadecimal. Is there any better way to do this.

I want to send `65030063002FFC2C` as the input to meter `101` and `66030063002FFC1F` as the input to meter with id `102' and so on. Only if the meter ID gets a match at the meter input, it would return the corresponding readings to the server. I have been trying to figure this out for so many days, but since I am new to PHP sockets and with very little knowledge on same, it's hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since no one yet answered, I did some digging and got a way around it. But it includes a loop.  So there was a couple of meters. I could sent data to the meter using socket write and for loop. The part which didn't make the above code work, was while sending a meter 100s of request packets, it actually receives the first 8 bytes and rejects the rest. So I added a delay with sleep(1) and the code worked like charm